# Reading .txt file on ComboBox by splitting

Tags: c#, windows, combobox

I'am trying to read from a textfile which is on my DLL but It only read first line (Duplicated)

**Text file like :**

```
100 UserName1   Job
101 UserName2   Job
102 UserName3   Job
103 UserName4   Job
104 UserName5   Job
105 UserName6   Job
106 UserName7   Job
107 UserName8   Job
```

So basically I'am getting "UserName1" duplicated on my ComboBox . (I want only to read the second cell. which means Usernames)

**my code :**

```
try
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Application.StartupPath + "/MyLists.dll");
    System.Resources.ResourceManager resourcemanager = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("ClassLibrary1.Properties.Resources", assembly);

    string[] strArrays15 = resourcemanager.GetString("JobList").Split('\t');

    for (int t = 1; t < (int)strArrays15.Length; t++)
        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(strArrays15[1].Split('\n'));

    return;

}
catch (Exception ex )
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: You are looping using `t` as a counter but never use `t` inside your loop. Does that help?

Comment: use `comboBox1.Items.AddRange(strArrays15[t].Split('\n'));` instead of `comboBox1.Items.AddRange(strArrays15[1].Split('\n'));`

Comment: dosen't work . It will load all of them . and I just wanna load the second cell

Comment: Also the first split should be on \n not on \t and the second one on the \t and not on \n

Comment: @user3748153 Do you at least see that your loop doesn't make sense?

Comment: Already tried that . It's loading all of them . not just second cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that your resource string has `\n` as newline delimiter and `\t` as delimiter between columns of a line then your loop should be

```
try
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Application.StartupPath + "/MyLists.dll");
    System.Resources.ResourceManager resourcemanager = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("ClassLibrary1.Properties.Resources", assembly);

    string[] strArrays15 = resourcemanager.GetString("JobList").Split('\n');

    for (int row = 0; row < strArrays15.Length; row++)
    {
        string[] columns = strArrays15[row].Split('\t')
        comboBox1.Items.Add(columns[1]);
    }
    return;
}
catch (Exception ex )
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

A bit of error checking should be added but for now let's pretend that your resource string is well formed and there are no surprises in the formatting

Comment: Works like a charm , gracias :p

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your loop:

```
for (int t = 1; t < (int)strArrays15.Length; t++)
    comboBox1.Items.AddRange(strArrays15[1].Split('\n'));
```

You're always using `strArrays15[1]` which uses the first item. Change to use the `t` which your incrementing instead:

```
for (int t = 1; t < (int)strArrays15.Length; t++)
    comboBox1.Items.AddRange(strArrays15[t].Split('\n'));
```

Another way of writing this which would prevent this simple typo is:

```
foreach(String item in strArrays15)
   comboBox1.Items.AddRange(item.Split('\n'));
```

Comment: Using this won't help . It will load them like this 
100
UserName1
Job
101
UserName2
Job

etc .. I just want to load the second cell